# Rename [code-challenge] to something more site-specific

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

It seems that users are still using the [code-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) tag for challenge-oriented questions that do *not* correspond to the [site's occasional voted-upon challenges](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/code-challenge/info).  We already have the [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) tag for off-site challenge programs, but it's understandable that the two tags sound similar.

So, I propose that we rename this tag in a way that it will not be confused with the other, while still communicating its purpose.  If anyone has any ideas, please provide them.

Comment: Tags can be *renamed*? Is it *renamed*, or *recreated*?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Recreated, technically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the tag wiki states that these are community challenges, I suggest that the tag to be renamed to [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge).  This doesn't sound the same as [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge), and it's less-likely to be confused with anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend adding "review" in there somehow.  In fact, [review-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-challenge) works to disassociate it with any other competition I know of, and identifies it at least partially with the site.

Alternatively, how about [cr-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cr-challenge) ?

Comment: I don't know why I downvoted this. [review-challenge] is probably the best option.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: [review-challenge] sounds like the *reviews* are being challenged, not the given code.  [community-challenge], on the other hand, sounds like it's a challenge for the community, which is what these challenges are about.