# Proposal to rename [programming-challenge]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

In [Rename [code-challenge] to something more site-specific](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1658/9357), it was proposed to rename [code-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) to avoid confusion with [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge).  That renaming (to [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge)) has been completed.

However, part of the problem is that [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) could also be better named.

Answer (score 4):

I propose renaming [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) to [online-judge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-judge).  Many of those problems have similar characteristics:

- Accept one line on standard input telling your program how many test cases follow. Each subsequent line of input, with space-delimited fields, represents one test case. Your program should read each line and print the corresponding answer.
- Some other online judges require your code to implement a specified API instead.
- Most of the time, the author is complaining that the code fails to scale up, or fails to produce the correct output for some input.

One kink with this proposal is that some questions, notably ones from Project Euler, don't fit that model exactly.  We would therefore revive the [project-euler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) tag.  (Frankly, I never really liked lumping Project Euler questions with the online judge questions.)

So, we would end up with [online-judge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-judge) and [project-euler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-euler), both of which should be unambiguous in meaning and unlikely to be confused with anything else.

Comment: What about other sites, such as CodeChef?  I don't think we need a separate tag for that.

Comment: I don't think we would need a [code-chef] tag, since those questions would fit the [tag:online-judge] model. The [tag:online-judge] questions tend to be very similar, regardless of where they come from.

Comment: Okay.  If this does get approved, I wonder how this will be cleaned up.

Comment: Tag renaming shouldn't be difficult. Retagging the [tag:project-euler] questions is a bit more disruptive, but isn't difficult — and it was only in the last few months that [tag:project-euler] has been merged with [tag:programming-challenge].

Comment: I never merged it, just synonymized it.  That would help us out, considering merging cannot be reversed directly.  I'm okay with helping out on the cleanup.

Comment: Someone posted a CR for their solution to a [LeetCode Online Judge](https://oj.leetcode.com/) problem. However, this site has you implement a provided method stub; you don't do any I/O. Thus I'm not quite sure why we should keep [project-euler] separate, other than it's popular and been around a long time.

Comment: Instead of [tag:project-euler], may I suggest [tag:code-kata] ?

Comment: Code kata is not an intuitive name at all for me

Comment: www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer does not follow the model either